# PrimeFaces Menubar options hidden by <p:media> component

Tags: html, css, flash, jsf-2, primefaces

In my application, I use PrimeFaces's  and  to organize the content. In one of the pages, I embed a YouTube video using  component. Unfortunately, as you can see from the below picture, my sub-menus were hidden by the flash player.

[image: Hidden sub-menus]

To be more precise, I put  inside the center layout unit. The top menu bar is on its own, I don't have top layout unit.

Since I have little experience in CSS, I'd be very grateful if you could show me how I can solve this problem.

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=flash+z-index) caused by the Flash player and actually not directly related to JSF. You basically need to set `wmode` parameter of the Flash player to `opaque`. You can do that by embedding it as `<f:param>` in the `<p:media>`.

```html
<p:media ...>
    <f:param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
</p:media>
```

Another `wmode` value which can also possibly solve this problem is `transparent`.

```html
<p:media ...>
    <f:param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</p:media>
```

Try the one and the other in as much as possible different browsers to see which fixes it the best in your particular case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried `opaque` in IE, Firefox and Chrome and it worked perfectly :D.